# How can I change the density of an object based on material?

Tags: physics

I have an object made in a single mesh with different materials applied to it (by face).

Is there a way to simulate its center of gravity considering the material's different densities?

Right now blender uses just a single material for the whole object if i am not mistaken.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Blender doesn't use materials to calculate the object center, it either uses the default shape primitive center or can use the geometry to calculate it's centroid.